# Como centralizar um menu (div) fixo?

Tags: html, css

O menu deve ser fixo e por isso usei o `position: fixed;`. Quando uso o `margin: auto`, que é para centralizar uma `div`, não funciona...

```css
#menubarra {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menubarra"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`Fixed` fica relativo ao `viewport`, então vc tb tem que declarar um `left` e `right` para o elemento

```css
#menubarra {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="menubarra"></div>
```